# {jpillora/chisel} High RAM usage on ARM by Chisel

Tags: memory, websocket, ram

I am using [jpillora's Chisel](https://github.com/jpillora/chisel) for WebSockets. I needed to use Chisel on ARM. I cross compiled it and reduced the binary size using the following two commands:

```sh
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build -ldflags "-w -s"
~/go/src/github.com/pwaller/goupx/goupx --brute chisel
```

However, when I run the chisel binary on the ARM board (512MB RAM), I find that it is taking a huge amount of RAM.

The "top" yields an output of usage of 161% and 775m! However, the difference of output of "free" command taken before and after the execution of chisel client is ~6MB.

I ran strace too, and the sum of all mmap2 memory allocated is 700MB+.
The command I executed to connect to the server:

```
./chisel client --fingerprint <> 10.137.12.88:2002 127.0.0.1:9191:10.137.12.88:9191
```

Is there some way to optimize / reduce the RAM usage on Chisel?

Any pointers would be helpful!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reduce the VSZ to ~279m (i.e by ~60%) by modifying the arenaSizes in malloc.go (/usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go).